# Paging in XsltListViewWebPart is not working perfectly when added programmatically

Tags: 2013, xslt-list-view-web-part, paging

I want to place a list view of the document library using `XsltListViewWebPart`.

My is as below:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("XXX/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPFile page = web.GetFile("Pages/webparts.aspx");
        if (page != null)
        {                        
            page.CheckOut();
            SPLimitedWebPartManager wpmgr = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            SPList docLib = web.Lists["Documents"];
            SPView docView = docLib.DefaultView;
            if (docLib != null)
            {
                XsltListViewWebPart view = new XsltListViewWebPart();                            
                view.ListId = docLib.ID;                            

                SPView lstView = docLib.DefaultView;
                view.Toolbar = "";
                lstView.RowLimit = 10;
                lstView.Paged = true;                            
                lstView.Update();                          

                view.AllowClose = false;

                view.AllowConnect = false;

                view.AllowEdit = false;

                view.AllowHide = false;

                view.AllowMinimize = false;

                view.AllowZoneChange = false;
                view.ViewGuid = lstView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();


                view.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.TitleOnly;
                wpmgr.AddWebPart(view, "Header", 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After executing above code web part is added successfully with paging but I am facing an issue that I can not go to previous page as I can go with standard page library view paging.
For example, I have given `RowLimit = 10` and if I have 15 documents in the library, I can go to next page but cannot go back to previous page.

Below are images of pages where the `XsltListViewWebPart` is placed. And I have 13 documents in my documents library.

[image: Page 01 of XsltListViewWebPart]

[image]

How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some experiments on the page where the web part was added.

First I edited the web part then simply save the web part. It started showing the button to go previous page.

Finally, got the answer for my issue that I needed just single line of code make it work.

The final code is :

```
view.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.TitleOnly;
wpmgr.AddWebPart(view, "Header", 0);
wpmgr.SaveChanges(view);
```

Remaining things are same in my code: just add `wpmgr.SaveChanges(view);` after adding the web part in the page. It would work perfectly.

Hope, this saves the time of others..!!! :-)